# Error while getting the access token(oAuth based authentication) through postman in magento v2.2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, token, postman

I must include **oauth_verifier** request parameter in the Authorization header in the postman call to get access token from request token through postman in **magento v2.2**,

I could generate the access token and access token secret using integration (keeping the Callback and Identity link URL blank). But I dont want to use that way. I want to use POST APIs to get request token and access token

I am trying to get the access token using POST /oauth/token/access which requires oauth_vefirier as one of the parameter.

I got this error

```
oauth_problem=oauth_verifier+is+a+required+field.
```

- Where does the oAuth verifier token come from ???

First Step I did
[image: First Step I did]

Sample Response
[image]

Second Step that I got error
[image]

**Error Message**
[image]

Comment: OAuth verifier token is sent to the callback URL that you specify when creating the integration, on activating the integration. You should store it in DB along with the shop URL. When you are trying to get an access token later, you again need to query db and get the verifier token and attach it to your request.